# Can Ubuntu Pro tokens be deactivated remotely?

Tags: ubuntu-pro

Does Ubuntu Pro have any fine token management, such as remotely deactivating the token from a specific machine? Or is it even possible to see information on the computers that use your token? Is it possible to recreate the token for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ubuntu Pro have any fine token management, such as remotely
> deactivating the token from a specific machine?

I do not think so, but one can always issue a `sudo pro detach` via ssh.

> Or is it even possible to see information on the computers that use
> your token?

For tokens associated to your account, one can access https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard, see some information as the number of active machines (number of machines associated with a token that contacted Ubuntu Pro in the last 24 hours), and modify the enabled services associated to a token.

For Ubuntu Pro instances directly spawned in clouds, the token is fetched and handled by the Pro client and cloud on first boot, so the token is not associated to your account.

> Is it possible to recreate the token for any reason?

Tokens associated to your account can be seen in https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard.

For Ubuntu Pro instances directly spawned in clouds, the token management is meant to be transparent for the user, so one should not need to recreate any token.